# Determine if xml nodes has same ancestor

Tags: powershell, xpath

```
[xml] $xml = "<TOP>
    <A>
        <X><match>yes</match></X>
        <X><match>yes</match></X>
        <Y><match>yes</match></Y>
    </A>
    <B>
        <X><match>yes</match></X>
        <Z><match>yes</match></Z>
    </B>
</TOP>"

$matches = $xml.SelectNodes("//match")
$previous = ""
foreach($match in $matches)
{
    $current = $match.ParentNode.ParentNode.Name
    if($current -eq $previous)
    {
        write-host "Same ancestor!:" $match.ParentNode.ParentNode.OuterXml
    }
    $previous = $match.ParentNode.ParentNode.Name 
}
```

Using xpath and powershell I find all matching nodes, but also want to determine if the nodes have the same ancestors X level op. In the example I have compared 2 level up and only for 2 nodes (current and previous) at the time. I believe there is a better solution using xpath, when looping the matches

I have tried using something like `/TOP/A[//X[1]/match][//X[2]/match]` but is stuck

Basically I want to tell that of the 5 matching nodes 3 share the same ancestor whereas the last 2 node share the same ancestor.

Comment: So you want `$matches |Group-Object {$_.ParentNode.Name}`

Answer (score 2):

You should not compare the names, you should compare the nodes *themselves*.

```
$xml = [xml]"<TOP>
    <A>
        <X><match>yes</match></X>
        <X><match>yes</match></X>
        <Y><match>yes</match></Y>
    </A>
    <A>
        <X><match>yes</match></X>
        <Z><match>yes</match></Z>
    </A>
</TOP>"

$matches = $xml.SelectNodes("//match")

foreach ($match in $matches)
{
    $current = $match.ParentNode.ParentNode
    if ($current -eq $previous)
    {
        write-host "Same ancestor!:" $current.OuterXml
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Different ancestor!:" $current.OuterXml
    }
    $previous = $current
}
```

prints

```
Different ancestor!: <A><X><match>yes</match></X><X><match>yes</match></X><Y><match>yes</match></Y></A>
Same ancestor!: <A><X><match>yes</match></X><X><match>yes</match></X><Y><match>yes</match></Y></A>
Same ancestor!: <A><X><match>yes</match></X><X><match>yes</match></X><Y><match>yes</match></Y></A>
Different ancestor!: <A><X><match>yes</match></X><Z><match>yes</match></Z></A>
Same ancestor!: <A><X><match>yes</match></X><Z><match>yes</match></Z></A>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, Consider

```
count($a/ancestor::X | $b/ancestor::X) = 1
```

to test if `$a` and `$b` have the same X ancestor.

From XPath 2.0 there is an "is" operator to make this simpler

```
$a/ancestor::X is $b/ancestor::X
```

Comment: In principle yes, but in PowerShell that's difficult, since `$a` and `$b` will be stand-alone XML nodes that don't go back into one XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mathias R. Jessen I think I will go for a solution looking something like this.

```
[xml] $xml = "<TOP>
    <A>
        <X><match>1</match></X>
        <X><match>2</match></X>
        <Y><match>3</match></Y>
    </A>
    <B>
        <X><match>4</match></X>
        <Z><match>5</match></Z>
    </B>
</TOP>"

$matches = $xml.SelectNodes("//match")

$go = $matches | Group-Object {$_.ParentNode.ParentNode.Name}

foreach($g in $go)
{
    foreach($o in $g.group)
    {
        foreach($match in $matches)
        {
            if($match -eq $o)
            {
                write-host $g.name $o.OuterXml 
            }
        }
    }
}
```